# Is there any tool that supports Visual Studio 2015 to produce a code map?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-map

Now I got the task which is tracing MVC 6 initial flow via visual studio 14 CTP, However the visual studio 14 CTP does not support code map function so far, so I would like to know whether has any tool to do this job, especially the tool support Visual studio 14 CTP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC6 is pre-release software and some of its functionality is significantly different than typical project types supported by Visual Studio. As such, some Visual Studio tools - like Code Map - will not support the new ASP.NET until its architecture is stabilized, i.e. closer to its release.